# Is there a way to create a series of UIAlertViews that are daisy chained into a decision tree?

Tags: uialertview

Is there a way or a model by which I could create a "Choose your own adventure" type app using UIAlertViews?

Answer (score 1):

While this is not a direct answer to the question, what you're going for here is going to provide a less than ideal user experience. Alerts are jarring and not really meant to be a constant UI element but more of an occasional interruption.

That said, if you do want to do something like this, using a block handler pattern rather than a delegate pattern will make the logic of your app much simpler and easier to follow.

For Xcode5/iOS7, I would recommend taking a look at [BlocksKit](https://github.com/zwaldowski/BlocksKit) which includes a category on `UIAlertView` to use completion blocks instead of a delegate.

New in iOS8 is the [`UIAlertController`](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/PRERELEASE/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html) class which handles this very similarly without a need for an external component. It does require iOS 8 to use though.